# on print of multiple html tables, random cells are modified even with no css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I am trying to print out a table with no css style sheet and all 3 browsers, chrome,firefox and safari a reacting bizarrely when printing out. my table has only id's, class, and names. No styling in the html of the table.

here in firefox. seems random td's are modified in height?

[image: here is one of the problems in a random table]

[image: and here another table]

and here in safari

[image: safari]

[image]

Any ideas? much worst in webkits it seems. 
help would be great on this one. am completely lost here. a simple html table!!!

Thanx

here is a print preview in chrome

[image]

Comment: provide some code, like this it's not solvable

Comment: here is a fiddle. just copy this table 10 or 20 times and you will see some of the <tr> seem to go wrong !!  http://jsfiddle.net/adrienboufflet/fvq40h02/

Comment: I've repeated the line until there are ~4k lines - all is correct displayed: http://jsfiddle.net/hyhhwcr9/ Have you changed the zoom levels in your browsers? try to set them to 0 and have a look if it works ...

Comment: yes your fiddle works but this is one big table. my problem is that when I duplicate this table x number of times, things start to go wrong.

Comment: viewing the tables in the browsers works fine but its when I want to print out or save a pdf.

Comment: oh, you've copied the whole `table` tag?

Comment: yes. copying the whole table tag multiple times.

Comment: just tested, works fine, pdf looks ok... can't imaging any other thing that zoom, or you're missing an style included somewhere...

Comment: just added a picture to show the print out view. all settings are set to default in both browsers.

Comment: The problem seems to be a page break problem. just added this css to force 1 table per page and the problem disappeared.  @media print {
    table {page-break-before: always;}
}